# is it possible to load 2 totally different index.HTML pages in angular 2

Tags: angular

is it possible to load 2 totally different index.HTML pages in angular 2 - so that when core domain is called the Landing Page comes up and if a link on it or a /route-link is called then angular 2 is loaded in the browser and instantiated to show that route/admin panel.

Basically want to keep Static HTML files for landing page and admin angular 2 - 2 separate website integrated with each other in the same root folder of the Server

Comment: this can be made via server-side routing...

Comment: I am using AWS S3 - can you explain how is it possible - thanx for your help

Comment: What stack uses your server? Node?

Comment: AWS S3 - is static File hosting only .. it does not have a Node Server Implementation nor any other - Plain simple http - request handler is done in S3

Comment: ok, you should use a pure javascript router in your index and, when need for angular, perform an http redirect to the html file that instantiates angular...

Comment: any example code or link you have ??